# Understanding WADL specification - document required post parameter

Tags: web-services, rest, wadl

I have two questions regarding the [WADL-specification](https://wadl.java.net/wadl20061109.pdf).

Their example `http://foo.it/widgets/123?custId=cust1234&verbose=true` contains two optional query parameters `custId` and `verbose`.

1. Is the given node structure in their example correct?
2. Could you give or correct my example of a post-request with manadatory parameters?
3. What does `header` mean and where would i have to place the xml - is my understanding correct?

#### Quote from 2.8.1 Query Parameters

> Child param elements (see section 2.12) of a resource or request with
>   a style value of ‘query’ represent URI query parameters as described
>   in section 17.13 of HTML 4.01[4]. The runtime values of query
>   parameters are sent as URI query parameters when the HTTP method is
>   invoked.
>
> The following example shows a resource with a generative URI
>   that supports a single HTTP method with a two optional query
>   parameters

This is their example

```
<resources base="http://example.com/widgets">
    <resource path="{widgetId}">
        <param name="custId" style="query"/>
        <method name="GET">
            <request>
                <param name="verbose" style="query" type="xsd:boolean"/>
            </request>
            <response>
            ...
            </response>
        </method>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

It seems to me that the sequence of `resource param method request param` or the hierarchy is incorrect

```
  resource 
  ++ param      <-- why is this here
  ++ method
  ++++ request
  ++++++ param    <-- and the other one here
  ++++ /request
```

#### Question 1: Place of parameter inside node

I would have expected that the parameters are all inside `<request>` like here

```
<resource path="{widgetId}"> 
   // removed custId
    <method name="GET">
       <request>
           <param name="custId" style="query"/>
           <param name="verbose" style="query" type="xsd:boolean"/>
        </request>
        ....
    </method>
</resource>
```

So this hierarchy

```
  resource 
  ++ method
  ++++ request
  ++++++ param      <-- all params are inside request
  ++++++ param    
  ++++ /request
```

Is my understanding correct how the params should be nested or does it not matter or does it have a different meaning?

#### Question 2: How would you document required post parameter

Is this snippet correct?

```
<method name="POST">
  <request>
    <param name="custId" style="query" required="true"/>
    <param name="verbose" style="query" required="true" type="xsd:boolean"/>
  </request>
  ....
</method>
```

#### Update Q3. Use and understanding of `header`

How do i have to understand: *header: Specifies a HTTP header for use in the request part of all child method elements of the resource type*

Would this be like the following example and the field `userId` would be part of the http-header in every request?

```
  <request>
    <param name="userId" style="header" required="true" />
    ....
 </request>
```

Thanks

#### First partial answer

At least based on the [wikipedia entry to WADL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Application_Description_Language) the required part seems to be correct

```
<method name="GET" id="search"> 
 <request> 
  <param name="appid" type="xsd:string" style="query" required="true"/> 
  <param name="query" type="xsd:string" style="query" required="true"/> 
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use WSDL or SOAP messaging, you define these elements (input, output operations ) which are called parts. These Parts uses a portion of definition that is called Schema.

This schema element is either part of WSDL or it may be a separate XSD document. And this schema element is what tells the format and rules.

Q1. The format seems incorrect, refer this example https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E41633_01/pt853pbh1/eng/pt/tibr/concept_UnderstandingWADLDocuments-7b7fd7.html

Q2. Example for post request

```
<method id="POSTWeatherStation.v1" name="POST">
    <request>
      <resource path="weather/{state}/{city}?forecast={day}">
        <param name="state" required="true" style="template" type="xsd:string"/>
        <param name="city" required="true" style="template" type="xsd:string"/>
        <param name="day" required="true" style="template" type="xsd:string"/>
      </resource>
```

Q3. Yes, it should be part of the methods which have parameters specified as header.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you address any of my questions?

Comment: Can you paste your WSDL file and the XSD here

Comment: I have no WSDL and no XSD. I would like to understand the WADL specification.